# SignalR The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms, signalr

I'm using SignalR to communicate between my ASP.NET server and Xamarin.Forms client. However, when I'm using https, HubConnection throws this exception when trying to .StartAsync() : `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`
However, when I'm using http instead, all works fine.
Please, help me!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I solved it by upgrading Xamarin.Forms shared project .NETStandard version to 2.1, and rewriting HubConnectionBuilder this way:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(Properties.Resources.ServerIPAddress + "/test",
                options =>
                {
                    options.WebSocketConfiguration = conf =>
                    {
                        conf.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                    };
                    options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = factory => new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }
                    };
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(Token);
                }).Build();
```

Comment: Please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.

Comment: Ok, this solved the issue in my case. What about security? Does this code just accept all certificates?

Comment: It would be much better replace HttpClientHandler to AndroidClientHandler. But how to do it for SignalR?

Answer (score 3):

```
 hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .WithUrl($"your host/chatHub", (opts) =>
     {
         opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
         {
             if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                 // bypass SSL certificate
                 clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                     (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
             return message;
         };
     }).Build();
```